# Why is this HTML range bar's value above 1 while its max is set to 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I set up an HTML range input as the seek bar for an HTML5 video player, like so:

```
<input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0" min="0" max="1" step="0.001">
```

My intention was for the range's value to be anywhere between 0 and 1, so that the slider's value (0.5, for example) multiplied by the video's length (5000, for example), would output the proper place in the video when the user slides the handle (0.5 * 5000 = 2500, for example).

But instead, this range input's value is outputting much larger values that I can't explain. (20,000 for example).

Code snippet to handle the input:

```
var $video = $("#fullscreen");
var video = $video.get(0);

// Pause the video when the slider handle is being dragged
seekBar.on("mousedown", function() {
    video.pause();
});

// Play the video when the slider handle is dropped
seekBar.on("mouseup", function() {
    // Calculate the new time
    var time = video.duration * seekBar.value;
    console.log("Video duration: " + video.duration);
    console.log("Seekbar value: " + seekBar.value);
    console.log("Seeked time: " + time);
    console.log("Seek Max:" + document.getElementById("seek-bar").max);
    video.currentTime(time);
    video.play();
});
```

Expected output:

```
Video duration: 5871.146667
Seekbar value: 0.5
Seeked time: 2935
Seek Max:1
```

Actual Output:

```
Video duration: 5871.146667
Seekbar value: 3.9127773334503213 
Seeked time: 22972.4896
Seek Max:1
```

**Why is this HTML range bar's value above 1 while its max is set to 1?**

Comment: just correct this ... var video = video.get(0); with var video = $video.get(0);

Comment: make a fiddle, hard to say without seeing the seekBar variable getting assigned. And also Exception's correction is right.

Comment: yep @Exception I made that mistake in simplifying for this question. I'll add a JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without a fiddle. What is `seekBar`? You call `seekBar.on()` so I assume it's a jQuery object. But then you are using `seekBar.value`, which has no meaning for a jQuery object.

If it is in fact a jQuery object, created like this:

```
var seekBar = $('input#seek-bar');
```

Then you should be able to use `seekBar.val()` to get the value.

Additionally, you use

```
document.getElementById("seek-bar").max
```

which can be better written as seekBar[0].max, since you've already gone to the trouble of traversing the DOM already to find your seekbar.

Comment: You're right. For some reason, the jquery object for a range input returns a very weird value for it's .value property. using seekBar[0].value fixed it.